# How to make custom name for training model from scratches

Tags: model, new-operator, spacy

Acctually  I created model(NER) with CLI (much faster), but I need custom name for each model. How I can do this ?

```
python -m spacy train ru SPB_data train.json test_new.json -n 99 -p ner 

python -m spacy package  SPB_data/model-final  out
cd out/SPB_data-1.0.0

python setup.py sdist
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name of the model in the `meta.json` file that is located in the output directory, in your case `model-final`. Internally, this will [happen](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/cli/package.py#L54) next:

```
model_name = meta["lang"] + "_" + meta["name"]
model_name_v = model_name + "-" + meta["version"]
main_path = output_path / model_name_v
package_path = main_path / model_name
```